# Is there a Dynamic Solution to this that someone might be able to explain?

Tags: vb.net

Ref: There are 20ish panels that need this event at visibility change, all with the same naming conventions being project_x (x being the panel number)

I'm not able to do an expectation vs reality on this code because I was not able to find how to best do this.

Further Explanation: On the event 'VisibleChanged' Which is controlled by an External Class, We want a way to apply this dynamically in a shorter code.
Sure we can do this and hard code everything in and it works fine, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this dynamically.

```
Private Sub project_1_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles project_1.VisibleChanged
        Try
            If project_1.Visible = True Then
               'There's code here but it's been omitted
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all relevant panels in form load and subscribe each to a single event handler method

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'assuming the panels are on the main form you would use Me
    'else you would use the name of the control that the panel is located within - e.g. SomeControlName.Controls...
    Dim panels = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel).Where(Function(panel) panel.Name.StartsWith("project_"))

    For Each panel In panels
        AddHandler panel.VisibleChanged, AddressOf PanelVisibilityChanged
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PanelVisibilityChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim panel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)

    Try
        If panel.Visible Then
            'assuming the picture box is within the panel
            Dim pictureBox = panel.Controls.Find($"{panel.Name}_img", True)(0)
            'There's code here but it's been omitted
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that if the panels are in a container, for example another panel, then instead of `Me` it would be `TheNameOfTheContainer`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, Thanks @Anu6is

Answer (score 2):

Yes, like this:

```
Private Sub panels_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
  Handles project_1.VisibleChanged,
          project_2.VisibleChanged,
          project_3.VisibleChanged,
          project_4.VisibleChanged,
          project_5.VisibleChanged,
          project_6.VisibleChanged,
          project_7.VisibleChanged
    Dim ctrl As Panel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)
    Try
        If ctrl.Visible = True Then
           'There's code here but it's been omitted
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

There are a couple of other ways to do this as well.  This is probably the cleanest for VB.net and your situation.

Comment: This is great, So we have a way to dynamically target the Panels. Thank you for such a quick reply, Something I failed to mention but someone caught it was that within this code we have a dependant Picturebox that is reliant on the name of the current object. So it would be named like such 'project_1_img' - Using your code, how would we scope this to dynamically target the images within the conditions branch we have? (I'm just assuming it would be a bit different, since we're now targeting two separate things)

Comment: @Xpektations I really don't understand what you mean by "dynamically" in this context, but if you can just change the control-type from "Panel" to "Control" in the code.  The `_VisibilityChanged` event is generic to Controls, so you should be able to handle either.

Comment: However, Control objects all have a `.Name` property, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll just iterate through our panels with their sub contents based on the current Naming property! @RBarryYoung - I'm going to take a bit of bother from what you and Anu6is submitted. Great stuff.